# Struts2, Ajax form not submit after validation error

Tags: struts2, token

I want to submit a form using ajax. For this i am using Jquery AjaxForm plugin. Form containing file and some data which needs to be submit using AJAX to struts2 action. First time form is submitting properly and i am getting error message which expected as i and doing some server side validation. But when i submitting form second time form with correct information the form not submitting to the action.

I have search for the issue, and i came to know it is due to token i am using, as second time token value was miss matched.

How would i can resolved this issue or some hit by which i can update form token value.

```
Code Sample:

<s:form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="usrUploadFormat" method="post" validate="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="fields-format-wraper ulb-upload-wrapper">
        <div class="error-wrapper">
            <s:fielderror/>
            <s:actionerror/>
            <ul class='errorMessage passwdError' id="errors">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="fields-row" style="display: none;">
            <div class="doc-check-wrapper">
                <s:token/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fields-row" id="doc-field">
            <span><s:label cssClass="label" value="Upload*"/></span>
            <span><s:file  cssClass="inputFields inputs format file" id="formatToUpload" name="formatToUpload" accept="application/ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"></s:file> </span>
         </div>
         <div class="fields-row formats-row btn-upload-wrapper">
            <span style="float:left;margin-left: 175px;"><input type="button"  class="btn-submit" value="Upload" name="auth" id="upload-now"/></span>                            
        </div>
    </div>
</s:form>
```

Ajax Calling for the form:

```
var options = {
    success: function(msg) 
    {
        var msgs = msg.split(":");
        if(msgs.length>0){
            if(msgs[0] == "Error"){
                $('.errorMessage.passwdError').empty();
                var counter = 0;
                $.each( msgs, function( key, value ) {
                    counter++;
                    if(counter == 1)
                        return;
                   $('.errorMessage.passwdError').append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
                });
                window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.hideLoading();
            } else{
                alert(msgs[0]);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(err)
    {
       jAlert("unable to upload file.",
        'Upload Report Format Error.',
        function (r) { 
            if(r == true){
                window.parent.location.reload();
                window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
            }
       });
    },
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
       window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.showLoading(); 
    }
};
$("#uploadReportFormatsForm").ajaxForm(options);
```

struts.xml

```
<interceptor-stack name="pmidcCSRFStack">  
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession">
        <param name="includeMethods">*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="dataSourceCheck"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
 </interceptor-stack>
 <action name="usrUploadFormat" class="com.org.pmidc.action.ULB_UploadReport">
    <interceptor-ref name="pmidcCSRFStack"/>
    <result name="invalid.token" type="tiles">csrfError</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">application/pdf,application/ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</param>
            <param name="maximumSize">1048576000000</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
</action>
```

When i submitting form with server side error like choose wrong format pdf, or file size is greater then allowed, then i get error size or file format is not allowed. Once i correct all the error and submit form again the then request not go to the action execute, instead response is return from token interceptor. I came to know this because of log when warning show that token mis matched.

It means it is clear that form is not submitting due error with token. So the solution would be update token value, here i stuck. How to update or refresh token value for next time i submit form.

Comment: 2 broad, sorry. But you should be able to find something already written on SO, I remember I've seen stuff... it's just not possible to answer without knowing anything (what you're exactly doing, what your code looks like, what level of knowledge do you have on the various subjects involved, etc). Try to boil it down to more granular, atomic question(s)

Comment: Ok i'll put home code.

Comment: I have updated my question please look.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of `struts.xml`.